# Calculate this triple integral

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus

Integrate the function $f(x,y,z)=e^{-x-y-z}$ in the region $R=(x,y,z) |0<x<y<z<\infty.
$

I calculate that and the result was 1/6 but I don't know if my integral limits are OK.

Answer (score 5):

Actually you need only find the integral $I$ over all positive $x,y,z$ and then divide by $3!=6$, because $I$ is the sum of the integrals over 
the six regions $0<x<y<z$, $0<x<z<y$, $0<y<x<z$, etc., which are
equal by symmetry.  And $I$ is easy because it factors into
$$
\left( \int_0^\infty e^{-x} dx \right)
\left( \int_0^\infty e^{-y} dy \right)
\left( \int_0^\infty e^{-z} dz \right)
= 1 \cdot 1 \cdot 1 = 1,
$$
so the integral over $0<x<y<z$ is indeed $1/6$
(and likewise in $n$ dimensions the analogous integral is $1/n!$).

Answer (score 1):

What are your integral limits?

The integral of $f(x,y,z)$ over the given region $R$ is given by

$$\int_0^\infty \int_0^z \int_0^y e^{-x-y-z} dx dy dz \\= 
\int_0^\infty \int_0^z e^{-y-z} - e^{-2y-z} dy dz \\=
\int_0^\infty \frac{1}{2}e^{-z}-e^{-2z}+\frac{1}{2} e^{-3z}dz \\=
\frac{1}{6}$$

The limits of integration and order of integration are practically given by the definition of the region $R$.

Comment: I use the limits 0<x<inf, x<y<inf and y<z<inf, but i think it's the same, thanks.